# xfail pytest tests from the command line

Tags: python, pytest

I have a test suite where I need to mark some tests as xfail, but I cannot edit the test functions themselves to add markers. Is it possible to specify that some tests should be xfail from the command line using pytest? Or barring that, at least by adding something to pytest.ini or conftest.py?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a command line option to do this, but if you can filter out the respective tests, you may implement `pytest_collection_modifyitems`and add an `xfail` marker to these tests:

*conftest.py*

```py
names_to_be_xfailed = ("test_1", "test_3")

def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    for item in items:
        if item.name in names_to_be_xfailed:
            item.add_marker("xfail")
```

or, if the name is not unique, you could also filter by `item.nodeid`.

Comment: This looks like it would work. Now a follow up question: is there a way to set a conftest.py file from the command line?

Comment: I don't think so, the `conftest.py` must be in the root path of the tests it is applied to.